# Reading Avro into spark using spark-avro

Tags: apache-spark, avro, apache-spark-sql

I'm not being able to read spark files using the spark-avro library. Here are the steps I took:

- Got the jar from: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.databricks/spark-avro_2.10/0.1
- Invoked spark-shell using `spark-shell  --jars avro/spark-avro_2.10-0.1.jar`
- Executed commands as given in the git readme:

  ```
  import com.databricks.spark.avro._
  import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
  val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
  val episodes = sqlContext.avroFile("episodes.avro")
  ```
- The action sqlContext.avroFile("episodes.avro") fails with the following error:

  ```
  scala> val episodes = sqlContext.avroFile("episodes.avro")
  java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class com.databricks.spark.avro.AvroRelation has interface org.apache.spark.sql.sources.TableScan as super class
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
  at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
  ```

Comment: Instead of pulling down the .jar file yourself you can just reference the package and the shell will pull down the package and any of its dependencies for you, using: spark-shell --packages com.databricks:spark-avro_2.10:1.1.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My bad. The readme clearly says:

```
Versions

Spark changed how it reads / writes data in 1.4, so please use the correct version of this dedicated for your spark version

1.3 -> 1.0.0

1.4+ -> 1.1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

I used spark:`1.3.1` and spark-avro: `1.1.0`. When I used spark-avro: `1.0.0`, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Since spark-avro module is external, there is no .avro API in DataFrameReader or DataFrameWriter.

To load/save data in Avro format, you need to specify the data source option format as avro.

Example:

```
val usersDF = spark.read.format("avro").load("examples/src/main/resources/users.avro")
usersDF.select("name", "favorite_color").write.format("avro").save("namesAndFavColors.avro")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession        

val spark = SparkSession.builder()
            .appName(appName).master(master).getOrCreate()

val sqlContext = spark.sqlContext
val episodes = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.avro")
                .option("header","true")
                .option("inferSchema","true")
                .load("episodes.avro")

episodes.show(10)
```